# Why does (x-(x/y)*y) evaluate to the same as x%y?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 9;
    int y = 2;
    int z = x - (x / y) * y;
    printf("%d", z);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this code print the value of `x % y`?

From a strictly mathematical standpoint, `(x/y)*y` is the same as `x`, so one might expect 0 to be printed if looked at in this way.

Comment: Are you asking why math works the way it works?

Comment: Ask your math teacher from elementary school.

Comment: `x-(x/y)*y` is mathematical implementation of `x%y`.

Comment: You might want to note that the `/` operator works different for integer and floating point types. Consult your basic C text book about the details.

Comment: I doubt that every elementary school math teacher knows the details of C integer division. This might not be most excellent question, but unclear what is being asked? Hardly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason has to due with how the `/` operator works with particular types.

The division operation `x/y` is performed as integer division because both operands are integer types.  So the resulting value has the fractional portion of the division truncated.

Multiplying this result by `y` will therefore not necessarily be the same as `x` due to the truncation of the result value.  The difference between this result and `x` is `x%y`.

From section 6.5.5 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *6* **When integers are divided, the result of the `/` operator is the
>   algebraic quotient with any fractional  part  discarded.**  If  the 
>   quotient `a/b` is  representable,  **the  expression `(a/b)*b  +  a%b`
>   shall  equal `a`**;  otherwise,  the  behavior  of  both `a/b` and `a%b`
>   is undefined.

So the standard explicitly states that this equality holds.

If either operand of the division was a floating point type, then `x-(x/y)*y` would always be 0 or a value very close to 0 due to the inexact nature of floating point operations.

Comment: I would have added the quote from the standard as that formula is actually how behaviour of `%` is defined. But aside from that, this answer doesn't really deserve the downvotes it got: It answers the question precisely.

Comment: @user694733 Good idea.  Edited.